# htaccess RewriteRule shows 404 error and does not hide index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a url shortener. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ index.php?redirect=$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I type example.com/Ran41D I get 404 error, when I type example.com/index.php I can see the filename in address bar.

I expect example.com/Ran41D to forward the url to example.com/index.php?redirect=Ran41D - which is working great, and to see in address bar example.com/ instead of example.com/index.php

Comment: Your last rule has a slash before the index.php, so why doesn't the other one as well?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried adding and removing slashes to both, that didn't work

Comment: This is not possible. All that is possible is that `https://example.com/Ran41D` stays visible in the browser's address bar. But not `https://example.com/` as you are trying to achieve. The rewriting engine can only do one thing at a time: either use the `Ran41D` for whatever you want, or forward to `https://example.com/` , but that would lose the query parameter.